# Get Canvas to stick next to other canvas vue.js

Tags: css, html, canvas, vuetify.js

I have a project that use multiple canvas elements. I have one canvas called gutter and then multiple groups of canvas that render as many times as needed. Each group contains three canvas layered over each other. I am using vue js and vuetify to work with all this. What I want is to place the canvas called gutter next to the first group of canvas. I have tried floating both elements to the left and that has not worked and variety of different div configurations and also display properties such as flex block and flex inline with no luck. I attached a picture to try and illustrate what I am doing, on the far left is the gutter that I want to move next to the other canvas. The blue boxes illustrate the groups.Each group has a name that renders on top of it.

[image: Layout]

## rendered layout in inspector

[image: Rendered Structure]

Comment: Try `canvas: display: inline-block` in your css

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto This sort of works. If I  set the display of the gutter canvas to inline-block it does set the left edge of the canvas to the left edge of the group of canvas. I want the gutter to line up next to the other canvas not on top of each other like this is doing. I tried adding a right margin but that had no effect. I also cannot not set the display of the other canvas to inline block as it ruins the alignment of the text and canvas.

Comment: Can you setup a https://jsfiddle.net with a simple version of your problem? It's almost impossible to help you further without your CSS code.